# iphone login system not working

Tags: php, iphone, sql

I have tried many times to get this to work but it doesn't work no matter what I try. I have researched many tutorials but with no luck of finding anything useful. Any tips or help please?!! Does anything seem to be wrong with the code?

```
- (IBAction)login:(id)sender {
    NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&pass=%@",usernameField.text, passwordField.text];

NSString *hostStr = @"http://new-host-3.home/login.php?";
hostStr = [hostStr stringByAppendingString:post];
NSData *dataURL =  [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [ NSURL URLWithString: hostStr ]];
NSString *serverOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];







if([serverOutput isEqualToString:@"Yes"]){
    UIAlertView *alertYes = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Succsess!" message:@"You are logged in!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alertYes show];
}

else {
    UIAlertView *alertFail = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Username or Password Incorrect"
                                                          delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alertFail show];

}

}


<?php
session_start();
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","monkeys","lian");

$u = $_GET['username'];
$pw = $_GET['pass'];

$check = "SELECT username,pass FROM members WHERE username='$u' AND pass='$pw'";

$login = mysqli_query($con,$check) or die(mysqli_error($con));

$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($login);

echo "$num_rows \n";
echo "$u \n";
echo "$pw \n";

if (mysqli_num_rows($login) >= 1) {
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($login);
echo 'Yes'; 
exit;
}

else {
echo ' No';
exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using NSMutableURLRequest, and definitely run it asynchronously.  You're service is probably expecting a POST for the login.  If so, set the HTTP verb, and put the post data in the request body....

```
NSString *hostStr = @"http://new-host-3.home/login.php?";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:hostStr];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&pass=%@",usernameField.text, passwordField.text];
NSString *postEscaped = [post stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *postData = [postEscaped dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

[request setHTTPBody:postData];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

                           if (!error) {
                               NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                               NSLog(@"response %@", string);
                           } else {
                               NSLog(@"error %@", error);
                           }
                       }];
```

Comment: I tried it but no matter what I put in the username and password fields, it returns no error.  How do I get it to login only when I put only the correct username and password.

Comment: This code's responsibility is to make a valid http post to the service.  The expected verb, the expected params, and the server behavior when those are sent, is all up to the web service.  The way to diagnose what's happening is with log output on this client and on the server (if you control it).  Feel free to paste the NSLog'ed response string here.

Comment: '2013-05-18 22:39:09.603 ServerTest[2294:11303] response <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /login.php was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.15 with Suhosin-Patch Server at new-host-3.home Port 80</address>
</body></html>'  This is the NSLog output

Comment: 404 likely means that there isn't a login.php to be found at new-host-3.home.  I think the iOS code works.  Can you prove your sever works with curl?